# How to add Internationalization to a Flutter Plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-intl

I made a Flutter plugin and I need to add Internationalization.
I have follow this tutorial like I usually do for a my Flutter app : [Internationalization in Flutter 1.22+](https://pascalw.me/blog/2020/10/02/flutter-1.22-internationalization.html)

But with a Flutter plugin there is no MaterialApp so I can't add this :

```
MaterialApp(
   localizationsDelegates: Translations.localizationsDelegates,
   supportedLocales: Translations.supportedLocales
)
```

So, is there a way to add Internationalization to my Flutter plugin so I can use this in my plugin ?

```
Translations.of(context).title;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found an answer in case someone need this :
You need to import the generated .dart file in your app to use it.

In `l10n.yaml` plugin file I have `output-localization-file=translations.dart` so I need to import this file in example/main.dart (or in any Flutter app using the plugin) :

`import 'package:MinimalExampleInternationalization/l10n/translationsUpdate.dart';`
and that's where I need to add this code :

```
 MaterialApp(
   localizationsDelegates: Translations.localizationsDelegates,
   supportedLocales: Translations.supportedLocales
 )
```

If your Flutter app that import this plugin already has Internationalization then you can add multiple `localizationsDelegates:` and `supportedLocales:` like this :

```
 MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: Translations.localizationsDelegates+TranslationsPlugin.localizationsDelegates,
          supportedLocales: Translations.supportedLocales+TranslationsPlugin.supportedLocales,
 )
```

Where Translations is the class generated by your app and TranslationsPlugin the class generated by your plugin.

Also note that right now there is a bug when generating the Internationalisation files with a Plugin so you can delete the l10n.yaml file and use this command instead : `flutter gen-l10n --arb-dir=assets/l10n --template-arb-file=string_en.arb --output-localization-file=translations.dart --output-class=Translations --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-synthetic-package`

More informations : [Flutter Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70840) and [Working Plugin Example with I18n](https://github.com/zackattack73/FlutterPluginExample)

Comment: Any ideas on how to override the plugins generated texts?